# Building open source dependencies using gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, build, build.gradle, build-tools

I really don't have much experience in developing let alone using build tools.

I was assigned a task to build dependencies locally and get the jar files.
say I have a list of deps (GAV) like this:-

```
1. org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.0-RC
2. com.auth0:java-jwt:3.18.2, etc
3. openapi4j:openapi-operation-validator:1.0.7, etc
```

So i was able to download the source code url from maven repository and source code from github programmatically, for example :-

1. org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.0-RC - https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin
2. com.auth0:java-jwt:3.18.2 - https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt
3. openapi4j-openapi-operation-validator-1.0.7 https://github.com/openapi4j/openapi4j

but there are many `build.gradle` files in different directories, how do I know which directory should I move into before running the `gradle build` command.
Things I have already tried and failed:-

- For deps like this openapi4j:openapi-operation-validator:1.0.7, i can directly go into the openapi-operation-validator folder in the Github repo (https://github.com/openapi4j/openapi4j ) and run the `gradle build` command, but not all projects are structured like that I guess?
- For deps like this com.auth0:java-jwt:3.18.2, the artifactId (java-jwt
  ) is already present in the github path (https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt), so i can run the `gradle build` command on the root github repo.
- From the [spring guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/) , among all the Gradle.build files available I can check which file has:-

```
    jar {
        archiveBaseName = <artifactId>
        archiveVersion =  <version>
    }
```

, then I can move to that dir and run `Gradle build`, but not all `build.gradle` files have this.

None of the above approaches are concrete, is there any other firm approach that I can use to tackle the problem?

Comment: Main question: Why do you want to build all those libraries from source? What are the reasons behind the plan?

Comment: I was instructed that jar's that are available online shouldn't be used for production and we have to build it by ourselves.

Comment: This is a strange approach. If this is about security, then it would be much better to use open source security scanners to find out what it possibly dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is generally correct.

You need to find the source code in github/gitlab/wherever, read the readme file and try to build it with whatever build tool was used there.

This may or may not work.

Comment: i'm trying to achieve this programmatically, is it feasible?
in the sense that, is there a common approach i can follow for all projects? without having to refer the readme file?

Comment: No, this is not possible. I guess, for a reasonably large project you will spend some weeks compiling code and maybe you can do 80% of the libraries. If you really (really really) need to compile everything you use from source (for whatever reason, read: nobody does this), then I suggest you use as few libraries as possible and prefer to write most of the code from scratch.